# may gcc be installed, but g++ does not work?

Tags: gcc, autotools

I have a problem with simple c++ programs...

I would like to install a program, but always have the error like "c++ compiler is unable to create executables"...

Now I tried to compile a simple "hello world" program, but I get errors as I would if I compile a c++ program with a c compiler ("`cout' undeclared"... although I included iostream)...

Now I am not sure, if g++ does not work on my machine?

Does anyone know about how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much in advance...
Chris

---

*Added* In response to Pax's answer:

Well, I think, my code is okay, I can compile it on another machine, and I use the namespace std...

So, it's not possible, that the configuration of g++ is mismatched or something like that...?

Comment: please post the command used to compile the Hello World app

Comment: Specify the operating system on which you are running.  Which version of G++ is installed (g++ --version)?  If it is Linux-based, did you install the G++ development headers?  What exactly was the command line and the set of error messages from 'hello world'?

Comment: And the short answer to your question is "Yes: you can have a working install of GCC without a working install of G++".  It would be a little unusual, but far from impossible.

Comment: The "c++ compiler is unable to create executable" message could be a permissions issue - can you create files in the directory where you are compiling?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try calling g++ directly? If you run:

```
g++
```

and it isn't installed, you should get the usual *invalid command* message, but if it is installed you should see something like:

```
g++: no input files
```

If you see that, then try running this:

```
g++ -o output-file input-file
```

replacing output-file and input-file with whatever. You can specify multiple input source files.

If g++ is installed, that should work. Normally you don't need to configure anything. If it doesn't work, then chances are its simply not installed.

On a debian-based machine you should simply be able to *apt-get install g++* should be similarly easy on other systems.

Comment: Yes, most often the problem is calling gcc -- which can itself use g++ but which doesn't set up a C++ environment, doesn't link to the C++ standard lib, and doesn't search teh C++ headers -- instead of g++ which handles a lot of things in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest help when trying to diagnose a problem when running configure is to look at config.log. The last error shown in that file is what caused the message you're seeing. I've seen plenty of instances where configure has output one error, but the log shows that the problem is with a completely different component (e.g., trying to use a library before it was checked for).

Answer (score 0):

"`cout' undeclared" most likely means a bug in your source.

Please either show us your source, or compile and run this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }
```

If above code does not compile (using e.g. `"g++ t.cc"`), show *complete* error message, and output from `"g++ -v"`.

If it does compile and run (which is likely), then there is nothing wrong with your g++, and the problem is with your source. The fact that your source compiles on a different machine means *nothing* -- your code could still be badly broken.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of calling the "wrong" compiler (using gcc instead of g++, see answer by Dan) it is **possible** but unusual to have gcc correctly built but g++ incorrectly built.

It is also possible that your system came with just gcc, and somebody installed g++ later into a different directory.  And if so, it is possible that the newer g++ is incorrectly set up.

Try running the commands

```
which gcc
which c++
```

From the command line.  If gcc is in, say, /usr/bin but g++ is in /usr/local/bin, then you may have this problem.  You can also ask to see if the versions match:

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the build-essential package on your machine and try again.  This fixed the same problem for me.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```